# Logging Messages

Tags: unix, logging

I'm very new to logging messages, it seems that after clearing logging messages from either "`/var/log/messages`" or "`/var/log/syslog`", none of the messages being log into either of the log file.

Clearing as in open up editor and delete all the messages.

Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys think I found out. `Syslogd` has to be restart.